# Screen capturing Flash

Tags: java, flash, screen-scraping, video-capture

Is there a way to play a SWF and screen capture it in a headless environment?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's Linux than you need a X server. You can either use vnc server or Xvfb.

Comment: what program would you use to screen capture and how?